# How to get day/month when i have this string input 2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-0300 in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Someone can help me?
I need to convert this date string "2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-0300" into this 14th/july in kotlin.

This is what i was trying to.

```
 private fun ajusteDeData(baseData: String): String{
    //Convert baseData into formatedDate ("14th / July")
    var input = "2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-0300"
    var output_formated = "14 / 07"
    /*
     * how to do this?
    */
    return output_formated
}
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Use `DateTimeFormatter.of()` with [a custom pattern matching that input format](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#patterns). Then [call `parse()` on that `DateTimeFormatter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery%3CT%3E)) to get a `LocalDate` (or whatever date/time type you want).

Comment: Could you me more specific or give me an example ??
The input data is comming on this format "2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-0300" and i need something like this "14 / July" or "14 / 07 ".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create constants:

```
const val INPUT_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" // for 2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-0300
const val OUTPUT_DATE_FORMAT = "d'th' / MMMM" // for "14th / July"
```

Declare function:

```
private fun convertDateToFormat(
        dateToConvert: String,
        inputDateFormat: String = INPUT_DATE_FORMAT,
        outputDateFormat: String = OUTPUT_DATE_FORMAT
    ): String? {
        return try {
            // First parse your string date in order to get Date object
            val dateObject = SimpleDateFormat(inputDateFormat, Locale.US).parse(dateToConvert)
            // Next format Date object to String
            dateObject?.run { SimpleDateFormat(outputDateFormat, Locale.US).format(this) }
        } catch (e: ParseException) {
            null // Most likely that 'inputDateFormat' or|and 'outputDateFormat' format doesn't fit 'dateToConvert' you trying to convert
        }
    }
```

Then simply call your function whenever you need converted string date:

```
var dateToConvert = "2021-07-14T00:00:00.000-0300"
val convertedDate = convertDateToFormat(dateToConvert)
```

**Note:** It is possible that `ParseException` will be thrown in case you pass wrong date format, so return type of fun `convertDateToFormat()` is `String?` **not** `String`

**Update**: Added corrections to `INPUT_DATE_FORMAT` and `OUTPUT_DATE_FORMAT` so that both formats match your specific case for input: **2021-07-13T00:00:00.000-0300** and for output: **14th / July**

Comment: I am still getting a error on parsing
/n detailMessage = Unparseable date: "2021-07-13T00:00:00.000-0300"

Comment: @GiovaniLeiteVitor I updated **INPUT_DATE_FORMAT** and **INPUT_DATE_FORMAT** constants, please verify if it works for you now.

Answer (score -1):

```
String parts[] = input.replace("T", "-").split("-");

String output = parts[2] + "/" + parts[1];
```